# Search in Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
$data = array
    (
    array("Ravi","Kuwait",350),
    array("Sameer","UK",400),
    array("Aditi","Switzerland",50),
    array("Akshay","India",250),
    array("rishi","Singapore",200),
    array("Mukul","Ireland",100)
    );
```

I want to put condition to the third row such that I can get entries of less than 300.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you meant *"the third **element**"* in each nested array.
Use `array_filter` function to get an array of elements, those third element's value is less than `300`:

```
$result = array_filter($data, function($v) { return $v[2] < 300; });

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $data = array
(
array("Ravi","Kuwait",350),
array("Sameer","UK",400),
array("Aditi","Switzerland",50),
array("Akshay","India",250),
array("rishi","Singapore",200),
array("Mukul","Ireland",100)
);

$newArray = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if($value[2] <= 100)
        $newArray[] = $value;

}

print_r($newArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the PHP function [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) :

**PHP**

```
function limitArray($array) {
   return ($array[2] <= 300);
}

print_r(array_filter($data, 'limitArray'));
```

[evalIN](https://eval.in/575311)